# App to toggle login apps

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, login-items

Is there an app to toggle login apps? I don't want junk like CleanMyMac, just a barebones toggle app.

Comment: Is going to **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > **Login Items** and deleting the app not working for you? Or do you just want to temporarily disable the app for certain logins?

Comment: I want to temporarily disable them. Also they don't all appear there, like OwlOCR, Karabiner, Vimac.

Answer (score 1):

[Lingon X](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) might be helpful. I use it as well as [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to wrangle all of the startup items and background agents on my machine.

Comment: That is not all - you need the System Preferences login items as well